# Get the date thats 2 Mondays ago

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a problem that i have been whacking my head over. No matter what day of the week it is I need the date thats 2 mondays ago. For example, if today is tuesday I need the monday before previous. I am using MS access to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the Weekday() function @mwolfe02 mentioned, and combine it with the DateAdd() function.  In these sample statements, I also used an IIf() function to tell DateAdd how many days to subtract from the starting date.

```
? DateAdd("d", IIf(Weekday(#2011/11/20#, 2) = 1, _
-14, -6 - Weekday(#2011/11/20#, 2)), #2011/11/20#)
11/7/2011 

? DateAdd("d", IIf(Weekday(#2011/11/21#, 2) = 1, _
-14, -6 - Weekday(#2011/11/21#, 2)), #2011/11/21#)
11/7/2011 

? DateAdd("d", IIf(Weekday(#2011/11/22#, 2) = 1, _
-14, -6 - Weekday(#2011/11/22#, 2)), #2011/11/22#)
11/14/2011
```

See Access' online help topics for those functions.

You didn't indicate whether you want to do this from VBA code or in a query.  And you didn't tell us where the date value comes from.  So I can't give anything more specific.

**Edit**: To do this in a query using the current date, try it this way:

```
SELECT
    DateAdd("d", IIf(Weekday(Date(), 2) = 1, -14, -6 - Weekday(Date(), 2)), Date())
    AS TwoMondaysAgo;
```

If you're running the query from within an Access application session, you could create a less nasty-looking query by building a VBA user-defined function to do the DateAdd computation, and then calling the udf in your query.

Comment: sorry, the date value will come from the current date and it will be used in a query

Comment: Oh man..it worked. Thanks for you work. I am total noob at access and didnt know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

The following uses only temporal functionality, which makes it more portable and may mean it performs better too:

```
SELECT DATEADD('D', ((
          DATEDIFF('D', #1990-01-09 00:00:00#, your_datetime_col) \ 7) * 7) - 7, 
          #1990-01-08 00:00:00#) 
  FROM YourTable;
```

Here's the VBA 'proof' to match HansUp's (except I'm using international date formats ;)

```
? FORMAT$(DATEADD("D", _
      ((DATEDIFF("D", #1990-01-09 00:00:00#, #2011-11-20 00:00:00#) \ 7) * 7) - 7, _
      #1990-01-08 00:00:00#), "yyyy-mm-dd")
2011-11-07

? FORMAT$(DATEADD("D", _
      ((DATEDIFF("D", #1990-01-09 00:00:00#, #2011-11-21 00:00:00#) \ 7) * 7) - 7, _
      #1990-01-08 00:00:00#), "yyyy-mm-dd")
2011-11-07

? FORMAT$(DATEADD("D", _
      ((DATEDIFF("D", #1990-01-09 00:00:00#, #2011-11-22 00:00:00#) \ 7) * 7) - 7, _
      #1990-01-08 00:00:00#), "yyyy-mm-dd")
2011-11-14
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Weekday()` function.  The rest is just math.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not overly familar with Access syntax but something alongs the lines of

```
DATEADD("d", -((datepart("w",now)-2)+14), now)
```

The 2 refers to Monday being the second day of the week.